# Controlled expansion applied to l3prop

Tags: expansion, l3prop

In the example below, Hook 1 and Hook 4 compile, not Hook 2 and Hook 3. Why?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \__erw_foo_prop{key=a}

\cs_set:Nn \__erw_prop:n {\use:c{__erw_#1_prop}}

\cs_set:Nn \__erw_prop_name:n {__erw_#1_prop}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_item:Nn
%{
  \__erw_foo_prop
%}
{key}

\exp_args:Nf\prop_item:Nn
{
  \__erw_prop:n{foo}
} {key} %                       Hook1

%\exp_args:Nf
%\prop_put:Nnn
%{
%  \__erw_prop:n{foo}
%}
%{jey}{c}%                       Hook2

%\exp_last_unbraced:Nf
%\prop_put:Nnn
%{
%  \__erw_prop:n{foo}
%  {jey}{c}
%}%                             Hook3

\prop_put:cnn
{
  \__erw_prop_name:n{foo}
}
{jey}{c}%                       Hook4

\exp_args:Nf\prop_item:Nn
{
  \__erw_prop:n{foo}
} {jey}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

I was hoping Hook 1 would be reproducible for `<fun>=put`, that way I could have perhaps come up with a meta function that works for both `item` and `put`. Regardless of whether this is feasible, I'd like to know what causes the compile error for Hook 2 and Hook 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* use `\prop_put:cnn` and `\prop_item:cn`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \__erwann_prop_name:n { l__erwann_#1_prop }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \erwann_prop_put:nnn
 {
  \prop_put:cnn { \__erwann_prop_name:n { #1 } } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \erwann_prop_item:nn
 {
  \prop_item:cn { \__erwann_prop_name:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__erwann_foo_prop {key=a}

\begin{document}

\erwann_prop_item:nn { foo } { key }

\par

\erwann_prop_put:nnn { foo } { jey } { c }
\erwann_prop_item:nn { foo } { jey }

\end{document}
```

This prints

a
c

---

Your attempted ways to do the above jobs are all against `expl3` conventions. Let's see

```
\exp_args:Nf \prop_item:Nn { \__erw_prop:n {foo} } {key}
```

The `f` variant reaches after `{` and starts “expansion up to the first encountered unexpandable token”, briefly f-expansion. The first level is

```
\use:c { __erw_foo_prop }
```

which becomes `\__erw_foo_prop` and then `\s__prop[...]`. The fact it seems to work is completely accidental.

Similarly for attempts 2 and 3, because in both cases `\prop_put:Nnn` finds `\s__prop` as its first argument, which it doesn't know what to do with.

Comment: This solution follows from Hook 4, I posted an update to clarify.

Comment: `prop_put` not fully expandable, but `prop_item` is. But I don't see how it explains the difference in behavior in the example.

Comment: @Erwann I've added a brief analysis. You're using the wrong approach.